# local network - ping local ip fail

Tags: linux, ip

I have trouble to connect to own host, here is details

debian is virtual host o virtual box

```
grek@debian-dev:~$ ip  addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK> mtu 16436 qdisc noop state DOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:ca:7c:4d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:feca:7c4d/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:10:27:65:17:4f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.56.103/24 brd 192.168.56.255 scope global eth1
    inet6 fe80::a10:27ff:fe65:174f/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:e6:da:23 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.4.15/24 brd 10.0.4.255 scope global eth2
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fee6:da23/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever



grek@debian-dev:~$ ip route
default via 10.0.4.2 dev eth2  proto static 
10.0.4.0/24 dev eth2  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.4.15 
192.168.56.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.56.103
```

my ip is 192.168.56.103

```
grek@debian-dev:~$ ping 192.168.56.103
PING 192.168.56.103 (192.168.56.103) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 192.168.56.103 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 5039ms
```

when i try ping it from remote machine

```
C:\Users\g>ping 192.168.56.103

Pinging 192.168.56.103 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.56.103: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.56.103: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.56.103:
    Packets: Sent = 2, Received = 2, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 1ms, Average = 0ms
Control-C
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your loopback interface is down...

Bring that up with `ifconfig lo up` and that should fix it.

Linux will normally use the loopback interface to ping itself, so even though eth1 has the IP address you're pinging, it will still try to use loopback when pinging itself.